# MySQL multiple row insert skip existing records

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to formulate an appropriate title for this. The problem is the following - A group manager can add events to groups in my website, when an event is added, members of the group that have selected so, need to be automatically added to the event as attendees. The problem is that some users may have already selected that they are attending the event before it was added in the group so their record will exist in the table with attendees and I will get the `Duplicate entry` error on my trigger.

I want to ask how to still have a primary key on 2 columns - i.e. not allow the same user to be inserted into `events_attendees` with the same `event_id`, but still insert the other rows in case of a multi insert?

table groups

`group_id | group_name ...`

table users

`user_id | user_name ...`

table events

`event_id | event_name ...`

table groups_members

`group_id | user_id | autoJoinEvents`

table groups_events

`group_id | event_id`

table events_attendees`

`event_id | user_id`

The trigger in question is on `groups_events` on `AFTER INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO events_attendees (event_id, user_id) 
   SELECT NEW.event_id, user_id 
   FROM groups_members 
   WHERE group_id = NEW.group_id AND autoJoinEvents = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the table structure so I can't tell if your indexes do already enforce uniqueness. Once you get that covered,  it's safe to assume that you could use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

```
INSERT INTO events_attendees (event_id, user_id) 
SELECT NEW.event_id, 
            user_id 
FROM groups_members 
WHERE group_id = NEW.group_id 
AND autoJoinEvents = 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE event_id=NEW.event_id
```

**Edit: This is the solution you added yourself**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO events_attendees (event_id, user_id) 
SELECT NEW.event_id, 
            user_id 
FROM groups_members 
WHERE group_id = NEW.group_id 
AND autoJoinEvents = 1
```

Both ways work. The difference is that the second one will ignore any errors, whereas the first one will only workaround the specific duplicate key issue

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is exactly the magic I need, but I am getting `blah blah check code that corresponds blah blah next to 'IGNORE'`

Comment: The syntax for that was `INSERT IGNORE ...` I've taken the liberty to edit your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I kind of mixed two possible ways to do this. There's a small caveat on INSERT IGNORE, but for your use case it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

## you can try

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE events_attendees DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(event_id,user_id);
```

Comment: are sure events_attendees table contain composite primary key?

Comment: Yes, all my indexes are correct in all tables. ( correct regarding to common sense )

Comment: do you try removing duplicates using table replacement?

Comment: I solved the problem, see the other answer. Still thanks for the effort!